# Running JabRef on Windows with OpenJDK

Tags: java, javafx

although I'm just trying to install JabRef, I am quite surprised that this seemingly easy task is giving me so much trouble.

I am using Windows 10 and I want to use JabRef (the most current version, which is 4.3.1). I do not have the JRE oder JDK for Java 8, but I have the Oracle Java 12 JDK.
JabRef requires a JDK 8 but I cannot download it from Oracle without login. (And since they are quite nosy, I refuse to sign up to get the download.)

So, I tried to use OpenJDK but that does not come with JavaFX, which JabRef requires. I also downloaded OpenJFX but now I am puzzled how to put everything together. OpenJFX is not "installed", so JabRef still complains that there is no JavaFX:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(LauncherEngine.java:81)
at com.exe4j.runtime.WinLauncher.main(WinLauncher.java:94)
at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.WinLauncher.main(WinLauncher.java:25)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.application.Application
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 15 more
```

So, my question is:

- How can I define where my OpenJFX is?, or
- Where can I get a JDK or JRE that contains JavaFX for Java 8?

Best regards!

Answer (score 2):

OK, I found a solution that worked for me. I simply used a JDK for Java 8 that includes Java FX: [ZuluFX](https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu/zulufx/).

I unstalled JabRef and reinstalled it. I was prompted to say where my JRE ist when I reinstalled it. After that, it seems to work fine.

Comment: Nice resource. Not yet updated for [JavaFX 12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX#JavaFX_12), though.